# Compare two intervals in case of equal

Tags: java

I am trying to compare two intervals which have `dateFrom` and `dateTo` to the `filterFrom`and `filterTo` is there a better way to compare two intervals with the border? Also in case `dateFrom` has the same date as `filterFrom` or `dateTo` has the same date as `filterTo` the method should return true.

**Code**

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class DateCompare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date filterFrom = dateFormat.parse("2017-01-02 08:00:00.0");
            Date filterTo = dateFormat.parse("2017-01-02 09:00:00.0");

            Date dateFrom = dateFormat.parse("2017-01-02 08:40:00.0");
            Date dateTo = dateFormat.parse("2017-01-02 09:00:00.0");

            boolean value = DateCompare.compareToIntervales(filterFrom, filterTo, dateFrom, dateTo);
            System.out.println("value: " + value);

        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private static boolean compareToIntervales(Date filterFrom, Date filterTo, Date dateFrom, Date dateTo) {
        if ((dateFrom.equals(filterFrom) || dateFrom.after(filterFrom))
                && (dateTo.equals(filterTo) || dateTo.before(filterTo))) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Unclear what you want.  Should it return true when they overlap (in any way)?  Because that's certainly not what the code is doing now.

Comment: @john16384 I am doing this in another method before calling `compareToIntervales`  if they overlaps I am cutting the time at the right position. Therefore I do not have this case at this position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this is similar to how an airline lets you pick a range of dates - these would be your filter start and end - and then you are comparing to your own dates. In essence, all you really want to do is check that both the start and end dates are within filterFrom and filterTo

A simple:

```
if (dateFrom >= filterFrom && dateTo >= filterFrom && dateFrom <= filterTo && dateTo <= filterTo) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;  
}
```

should do the trick (This is not the actual code, as I'm not sure Date is comparable by default, I think you use .after, .equals and .before as you have been), but the question is not quite clear on whether this is what you want.

Hopefully this helps you. It is worth noting that due to time zones, I have found its often best working with Epoch time which is built in to most languages. (Time since January 1st 1970)

Also, just to avoid the horrid:

```
if (this) {
    return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

simply replace it with:

```
return (this);
```

As for the comparisons, .after and .before are "left inclusive, right exclusive" so

```
date1.after(date2)
```

returns date1 > date2 - and implicitly !(date1 <= date2). We can use this to form

```
!date2.after(date1)
```

to return an inclusive date1 >= date2. This can be shown by:

`!(date2 > date1)`, so `!!(date2 <= date1)`, so `(date2 <= date1)`, so `(date1 >= date2)`

If this doesn't do what you need, or you need clarification, drop me a comment and I'll try and help :)

Comment: I just want to compare whether the dateFrom and dateTo within the filterFrom and filterTo and return true even if dateFrom  or dateTo equals filterFrom  or filterTo or both

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comment

Comment: Okay, I almost got the idea then, I've updated my answer to result in what I think is the correct one - if the dateFrom is >= filterFrom and dateTo <= filterTo, then we return True, otherwise false.

Comment: Would not be a good solution to write the following as you mentioned in your comment before `if (!dateFrom.before(filterFrom) && !dateTo.after(filterTo)) {return true;} else {return false;}`

Comment: I would instead write a sub-method called something like "dateIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(date1, date2)" and put that uglier code inside, with full documentation of how and why it works. That way your code remains readable. Otherwise make the Date class conform to the Comparable interface and the problem is solved, you can then use >= to your delight :)

Comment: Then you could have `return (dateIsGreaterThanOrEqualToDate(filterFrom, dateFrom) && dateIsLessThanOrEqualToDate(filterTo, dateTo))`. This is simply how I would code it, as I found it quick and efficient, but I understand if it doesn't work for you :)